# django for loop over list

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

i have a list created by `zip`.

```
list = zip(rating,image,comment)
```

all elements are querysets which are iterable.

Image is in this form:

```
Class image(request):
  location_id = models.IntegerField()
  bild = models.ImageField(upload_to=".",default='')
```

so, one location can have its multiple images.

now i am rendering that `list` to template and iterating over it to show the items. Say, one location has 2 Images. my problem is this:

```
  {% for rate, image, comment in list %}
     how do i show here both images of one location? 
     {{image.bild.name}} gives me only the first image
  {% endfor %}
```

thanks for help

Comment: What's a "location"?  Does each location have one rating, one comment, and a set of images?

Comment: @user9876, location is a class. but each location can have multiple rating, multiple comment, multiple images

Comment: Is there a reason that I'm missing why you have location_id as an integer and not a foreign key?  It seems like you're doing extra work with your zip when you could build a list of locations and then let Django's query sets give you the list of images for each location (and the rating / comments for same)

Comment: @Foon, now i changed my models as you said. i still dont understand how to get all images,ratings,comment of one location. :(. can you please give me sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Location` class should have fields or properties that give you the relevant ratings / comments / images.  Then you can just pass a list of `Location`s to your template.

If `Location` is a Django model, then the ratings / comments / images should each have a `ForeignKey` that points to `Location`.  In that case, Django will create properties on `Location` that point to the corresponding ratings / comments / images.  Use `related_name` to choose the name of that property, otherwise Django will invent a name.

Comment: thanks a lot. very good teaching. i learnt something very important from you .

Comment: now, how do i query for locations and its rating,image and comments?

Comment: @doniyor If you design your models like he said, you can get rating, image and comments for a location like `location.image_set.all()` or similar for others.

Comment: @Bibhas, so like this?: ``all_locs = Location.objects.all()``, 
``all_loc_images=all_locs.locations_image_set.all()``, here ``locations_image`` is a related_name of ForeignKey-to-Location in Image-Model. am i fine with this?

Comment: No. `for loc in all_locs: images = loc.image_set.all()`. `all()` sends you iterable queryset. You need iterate to get for each one. Try.

Comment: @Bibhas,but then how do i render them to template? if i do this: ``for loc in all_locs: images = loc.image_set.all()`` i dont get all images, i will get the last one, because images will be overwritten in every loop. after loop, do i still have to zip to render to template?

Comment: @Doniyor You can iterate inside the template if you want. Please read the docs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26994/discussion-between-doniyor-and-bibhas)